# Why Mongoexport yields 0 records?

Tags: windows, mongodb, command-line

I have a local mongodb 4.0 instance running with a collection called `test^3.0` under `patternbuilder` database.

I'm trying to export the content of the collection to a json file to be migrated to another server instance.

I've downloaded Mongo Database Tools version 4.0.

When running on the local server the following command:

```
mongoexport --db patternbuilder --collection test^3.0
```

I get the following response:

```
2021-04-27T20:51:40.018+0300    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2021-04-27T20:51:40.172+0300    exported 0 records
```

No matter what I tried on the command line switches - I still get 0 records exported.

Here is a snapshot of the local host server from Robot 3T

[image]

Why?

Comment: Have you tried the command `mongoexport` for another collection (small^3.0 for example)? Maybe the problem comes from the name of collection

Comment: How many records should there be?  Try running `mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("patternbuilder").getCollection("test^3.0").count()'`

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh: trying on small^3.0 yeilds the same - 0 records

Comment: @Joe: i don't have `mongo` exe - is it part of the admin tool set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the issue...

As I am on a windows machine, the `^` char is invalid in the command line.

So running the below  works just fine.

```
mongoexport --db patternbuilder --collection "test^3.0"
```

Thanks